# Best way to query most recent update to a group of records

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I am not sure my title describes my problem quite well enough. Here it is.

I am using MS Access and my SQL skill is very basic. I have a database with a lot of rows. The unique ID is a number. For each row there is a separate "file number" value which may be the same between rows. Let's say this is because the company updates an accounting record and assigns the new record (which has a dollar value) to the same "file number."

What is different between records with the same file number is the date they were created. So I want to return a table that shows only one row for each file number where that row is the most recent update to the file. This may require using MAX(filing_date), I think.

But my SQL isn't working. Having seen some posts about something similar on Stack Overflow, I wrote this:

```
SELECT table.unique_id, table.name, table.file_number, Max(table.filing_date) AS last_date, table.value 
FROM table INNER JOIN table AS filings ON table.file_number = filings.file_number 
WHERE table.form_type="update" 
GROUP BY table.unique_id, table.name, table.file_number, table.value
```

My SQL does not cut out the rows that I want to remove, the ones with the earlier updates to the file number.

I was able to remove the older-dated entries with a simpler query (one that did not have a self join) but only if I didn't include the unique_id or the value. That SELECT statement was just:

```
SELECT name, file_number, Max(filing_date) AS last_date
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Build a query that returns Max(filing_date) for each file_number then join that query to source table with compound join on date AND file_number fields.  Alternative is a correlated subquery using TOP N.

Comment: this works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can use calculated fields in Total queries (Group by) if the Groups have a unique alias.  The problem is then your stuck with a usually not so nice alias.  However, you usually bind your query to a form or report and you can re-alias to something user friendly at that time.

```
'TableB

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         ID         |    file_number     |       t_name       |      t_value       |    filing_date     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |                  1 | name1              |              $5.00 |          11/1/2023 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |                  1 | name2              |              $6.00 |          11/2/2023 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 |                  2 | name3              |             $15.00 |          11/3/2023 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 |                  2 | name3              |             $16.00 |          11/4/2023 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 |                  3 | name4              |              $4.00 |          11/5/2023 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

The key is using a unique alias here D: and F: and expression as the type for the calculated field.  You get the groups then calculate(lookup) the appropriate values based on the group.

```
'note the date delimeters # #
t_name: DLookUp("t_name","TableB","(file_number = " & [F] & ") AND ( filing_date = #" & [D] & "#)")

t_value: DLookUp("t_value","TableB","(file_number = " & [F] & ") AND ( filing_date = #" & [D] & "#)")
```

```
'sql pane:

SELECT TableB.file_number AS F, Max(TableB.filing_date) AS D, DLookUp("t_name","TableB","(file_number = " & [F] & ") AND ( filing_date = #" & [D] & "#)") AS t_name, DLookUp("t_value","TableB","(file_number = " & [F] & ") AND ( filing_date = #" & [D] & "#)") AS t_value
FROM TableB
GROUP BY TableB.file_number
ORDER BY TableB.file_number;
```

```
'results:

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         F          |              D               |       t_name       |      t_value       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |                    11/2/2023 | name2              | 6                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |                    11/4/2023 | name3              | 16                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 |                    11/5/2023 | name4              | 4                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You will have to decide how to handle ties and nulls.  Once a calculated field gets complicated it is usually best to abstract it to a public function in a code module:

```
'break tie with ID, replace dlookup in query with GetName(F,D)

Public Function GetName(F As Long, D As Date) As String
Dim ID As Long
ID = DMax("ID", "TableB", "(file_number = " & F & ") AND ( filing_date = #" & D & "#)")
GetName = DLookup("t_name", "TableB", "ID = " & ID)
End Function

Public Function GetValue(F As Long, D As Date) As String
Dim ID As Long
ID = DMax("ID", "TableB", "(file_number = " & F & ") AND ( filing_date = #" & D & "#)")
Debug.Print ID
GetValue = DLookup("t_value", "TableB", "ID = " & ID)
End Function
```

note: name, value, and Date are restricted words in Access hence t_name, t_value, filing_date